# Create one tick box then automatically ticked all other tick boxes with one click and also shows a button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So, I am trying to create a tick box that has this action:

1. The chkAll box , once been ticked, all other check boxes will also ticked.
2. When this action happens, a button will appear.

Then, another action I am trying to achieve is, if two or more checkboxes (not included the chkAll box is ticked, the same button will appear too.
This button is like a zip file button, so, only if more than one check box is ticked, it will appear (enabled to be used).

Currently the error I am facing is,
1.the chkAll check box needs to double click only then, the button appear.

2.And when I unclicked the chkAll check box, the button does disappear, but the other chckboxes are still ticked, which they suppose to be unticked too.

3.And when more than 1 check boxes are ticked, the button does not appear.

I am new to php, jquery, so will really appreciate any guidance from you.
Thank you.

```js
function toggleTick_Change() {
  $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
    if ($("#chkAll").prop("checked")) {
      $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
      $("#conditional-part").show();
    } else if ($("#chkT").prop("checked")) {
      if ($("#chkT").length > 1) {
        $("#conditional-part").show();
      } else {
        $("#conditional-part").hide();
      }
    } else {
      $("#conditional-part").hide();
    }

  });
}
```

```css
#conditional-part {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="container">

    <div id="page-container">

      <div id="page-header">
        <h3>Manage Deliveries</h3>
      </div>
      <div id="page-content">
        <table align="center">
          <tr id="conditional-part">
            <td class="input-group " role="group" aria-label="..." style="width: 85px; margin-top: 2px;">
              <input type="number" class="form-control input-xs" id="cpyCN{$rows.id}" name="cpyCN{$rows.id}" value="1" style="font-family: Raleway, Tahoma, Arial; font-size: 8pt; padding: 2px 2px 2px 10px;" placeholder="Copies" min="1" max="999" />

              <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button id="btnPrintCNTicked{$rows.id}" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" style="width: 40px;"
                                    onclick="javascript:btnPrintCNTicked_Click({$rows.id},$('#cpyCN{$rows.id}').val())">CN</button>
                            </span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>

        <div class="table-responsive" style="margin-top: 10px;">
          <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" style="font-size: 8pt;">
            <thead>
              <tr class="panel-default" style="height: 30px;">
                <th style="width: 20px;">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="chkAll" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;" onchange="toggleTick_Change()" />
                </th>
                <th style="width: 40px;">
                  #
                </th>
                <th style="width: 140px;">
                  DELIVERY NO / <br>DATE / TYPE
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr class="panel-default" style="height: 30px;">
                <th style="width: 20px;">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="chkT" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;" onchange="toggleTick_Change()" />
                </th>
                <th style="width: 140px;">
                  abcd
                </th>
              </tr>
              <tr class="panel-default" style="height: 30px;">
                <th style="width: 20px;">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="chkT" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;" onchange="toggleTick_Change()" />
                </th>
                <th style="width: 140px;">
                  1234
                </th>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <!--/id -page content-->
      </div>
      <!--/id -page container-->
    </div>
    <!-- /container -->
  </div>
  <!-- /content -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is mostly due to you triggering the change twice. once in line when a user selects it, Then again when you run your on change function.

Just add a class of `.js-checkbox` to your checkbox's and remove the onchange.

```
$('.js-checkbox').change(function() {
  if ($(this).attr('id') === 'chkAll') {
    if ($(this).prop('checked') === true) {
      $('.js-checkbox').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      $('.js-checkbox').prop('checked', false);
    }
  }
  
  const checked = $('.js-checkbox:checked');
  
  if (checked.length >= 2) {
    $('#conditional-part').show();
  } else {
    $('#conditional-part').hide();
  }
})
```

html in case you did not remove the onchange.

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="container">

    <div id="page-container">

      <div id="page-header">
        <h3>Manage Deliveries</h3>
      </div>
      <div id="page-content">
        <table align="center">
          <tr id="conditional-part">
            <td class="input-group " role="group" aria-label="..." style="width: 85px; margin-top: 2px;">
              <input type="number" class="form-control input-xs" id="cpyCN{$rows.id}" name="cpyCN{$rows.id}" value="1" style="font-family: Raleway, Tahoma, Arial; font-size: 8pt; padding: 2px 2px 2px 10px;" placeholder="Copies" min="1" max="999" />

              <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button id="btnPrintCNTicked{$rows.id}" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" style="width: 40px;"
                                    onclick="javascript:btnPrintCNTicked_Click({$rows.id},$('#cpyCN{$rows.id}').val())">CN</button>
                            </span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>

        <div class="table-responsive" style="margin-top: 10px;">
          <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" style="font-size: 8pt;">
            <thead>
              <tr class="panel-default" style="height: 30px;">
                <th style="width: 20px;">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="chkAll" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;" class="js-checkbox" />
                </th>
                <th style="width: 40px;">
                  #
                </th>
                <th style="width: 140px;">
                  DELIVERY NO / <br>DATE / TYPE
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr class="panel-default" style="height: 30px;">
                <th style="width: 20px;">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="chkT" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;" class="js-checkbox" />
                </th>
                <th style="width: 140px;">
                  abcd
                </th>
              </tr>
              <tr class="panel-default" style="height: 30px;">
                <th style="width: 20px;">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="chkT" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;" class="js-checkbox" />
                </th>
                <th style="width: 140px;">
                  1234
                </th>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <!--/id -page content-->
      </div>
      <!--/id -page container-->
    </div>
    <!-- /container -->
  </div>
  <!-- /content -->
```

Comment: Hi, it works, but still, i need to double click it for the first time only then the button appear .

Comment: Are you sure you removed the onchange off the checkbox's? ill update with the html.

Comment: I have fixed it, but now nothing happen. When clicked the check boxes, nothing happen. I there any diiference between $('.js-checkbox').change(function() {..} and using function toggleTick_Change() {}

Comment: I have added $(document).ready(function() before $('.js-checkbox').change(function() , now it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Two things you should be aware of:

- `#id` should be used sparingly (preferably not at all), I have changed all `#id` to classes (with the exception of the ugly button and input). The frequent use of `#id` will hinder if not cripple your code in the future. This is especially true if you use jQuery.
- onEvent attribute handlers are discouraged as well especially if you use jQuery.

> > ```
> > <button onclick="doNOTUseThisEventHandler()">...</button>
> > ```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".chkAll").on('change', function(event) {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $('.chkT').prop('checked', true);
      $(".conditional-part").show();
    } else {
      $('.chkT').prop('checked', false);
      $(".conditional-part").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.conditional-part {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="page-container">

      <div class="page-header">
        <h3>Manage Deliveries</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="page-content">
        <table align="center">
          <tr class="conditional-part">
            <td class="input-group " role="group" aria-label="..." style="width: 85px; margin-top: 2px;">
              <input type="number" id="form-control input-xs" class="cpyCN{$rows.id}" name="cpyCN{$rows.id}" value="1" style="font-family: Raleway, Tahoma, Arial; font-size: 8pt; padding: 2px 2px 2px 10px;" placeholder="Copies" min="1" max="999" />

              <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button id="btnPrintCNTicked{$rows.id}" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" style="width: 40px;"
                                    onclick="javascript:btnPrintCNTicked_Click({$rows.id},$('#cpyCN{$rows.id}').val())">CN</button>
                            </span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>

        <div class="table-responsive" style="margin-top: 10px;">
          <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" style="font-size: 8pt;">
            <thead>
              <tr class="panel-default" style="height: 30px;">
                <th style="width: 20px;">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="chkAll" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;">
                </th>
                <th style="width: 40px;">
                  #
                </th>
                <th style="width: 140px;">
                  DELIVERY NO / <br>DATE / TYPE
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr class="panel-default" style="height: 30px;">
                <th style="width: 20px;">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="chkT" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;">
                </th>
                <th style="width: 140px;">
                  abcd
                </th>
              </tr>
              <tr class="panel-default" style="height: 30px;">
                <th style="width: 20px;">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="chkT" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;">
                </th>
                <th style="width: 140px;">
                  1234
                </th>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <!--/id -page content-->
      </div>
      <!--/id -page container-->
    </div>
    <!-- /container -->
  </div>
  <!-- /content -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for telling me. For now, I can't change the id to class since, the  id=chkT actually in my code is this -> id="chkT{$rows.orderNo}", so, there are other function that will use this id to check on data.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 function toggleTick_Change(e) {
          if(e.checked){
          $('.chkBox').prop('checked',true);
     $("#conditional-part").show();
          }else{
          $('.chkBox').prop('checked',false);
    $("#conditional-part").hide();
          }
    }
 

$('.chkBox').click(function() {
    if ($('.chkBox:checked').length == $('.chkBox').length) {
      $('#chkAll').prop('checked', true);
$("#conditional-part").show();
    } else {
      $('#chkAll').prop('checked', false);
$("#conditional-part").hide();
    }
  });
```

```css
#conditional-part {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="container">

        <div id="page-container">

          <div id="page-header">
            <h3>Manage Deliveries</h3>
          </div>
          <div id="page-content">
            <table align="center">
              <tr id="conditional-part">
                <td class="input-group " role="group" aria-label="..." style="width: 85px; margin-top: 2px;">
                  <input type="number" class="form-control input-xs" id="cpyCN{$rows.id}" name="cpyCN{$rows.id}" value="1" style="font-family: Raleway, Tahoma, Arial; font-size: 8pt; padding: 2px 2px 2px 10px;" placeholder="Copies" min="1" max="999" />

                  <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button id="btnPrintCNTicked{$rows.id}" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" style="width: 40px;"
                                        onclick="javascript:btnPrintCNTicked_Click({$rows.id},$('#cpyCN{$rows.id}').val())">CN</button>
                                </span>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>

            <div class="table-responsive" style="margin-top: 10px;">
              <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" style="font-size: 8pt;">
                <thead>
                  <tr class="panel-default" style="height: 30px;">
                    <th style="width: 20px;">
                      <input type="checkbox" id="chkAll" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;" onchange="toggleTick_Change(this)" />
                    </th>
                    <th style="width: 40px;">
                      #
                    </th>
                    <th style="width: 140px;">
                      DELIVERY NO / <br>DATE / TYPE
                    </th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr class="panel-default" style="height: 30px;">
                    <th style="width: 20px;">
                      <input type="checkbox" id="chkT" class="chkBox" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;" />
                    </th>
                    <th style="width: 140px;">
                      abcd
                    </th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="panel-default" style="height: 30px;">
                    <th style="width: 20px;">
                      <input type="checkbox" id="chkT" class="chkBox" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;" />
                    </th>
                    <th style="width: 140px;">
                      1234
                    </th>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
            <!--/id -page content-->
          </div>
          <!--/id -page container-->
        </div>
        <!-- /container -->
      </div>
      <!-- /content -->
```

Comment: hi, thanks, i tried yours but didn't really work in my laptop. When I click the chkAll check box, nothing happen.  Is the  const checked = $('.js-checkbox:checked'); outside the toggleTick_Change function?  Didn't know why here in your snippet it works, but in my laptop, didn't.

Comment: copy all html code bcoz i added class name in checkbox

Answer (score 0):

the JS way...

```js
const
  myForm = document.querySelector('#my-form')
, chkbxN = myForm.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:not([name="All"])')
  ;
myForm.onsubmit = e => e.preventDefault()  // disable  form submit
 
myForm.oninput = ({target}) =>
  {
  if (target.name==='All')
    chkbxN.forEach(cb => cb.checked = myForm.All.checked)

  let CheckedBoxes = [...chkbxN].reduce((arr,cb)=>
    {
    if (cb.checked) arr.push(cb.name)
    return arr
    },[])

  myForm.All.checked       = ( CheckedBoxes.length === chkbxN.length ) 
//myForm.All.indeterminate = ( 0 < CheckedBoxes.length && CheckedBoxes.length < chkbxN.length )

  myForm.theButton.classList.toggle('noDisplay',(CheckedBoxes.length  < 2))

  console.clear()
  console.log( JSON.stringify(CheckedBoxes))
  }
```

```css
label      { display : block; }
.noDisplay { display : none;  }
#my-form > p {
  height     : 2.2em;
  background : #a9bccf;
  padding    : .3em;
  }
```

```html
<form id="my-form">
  <p>
    <button name="theButton" type="button" class="noDisplay">button</button>
  </p>

  <label> <input type="checkbox" name="All"  >All   </label>
  <label> <input type="checkbox" name="car"  >Car   </label>
  <label> <input type="checkbox" name="house">House </label>
  <label> <input type="checkbox" name="nice" >nice  </label>
  <label> <input type="checkbox" name="beach">Beach </label>
</form>
```

Comment: the ALL button, once unclicked, the rest of the checkboxes still ticked.

Comment: @BsozizGiiig Yep, this is what the PO only requests. And that's the usual and expected behavior for this stuff. Unchecking this button should not affect the others.

Comment: okay, Thanks, but i want the ALL button once unchecked, the rest also unchecked.

Comment: @BsozizGiiig I updated my code for this unspoken request on the original question. Is it OK?

Answer (score 0):

I'll have to admit, my jQuery is pretty rusty. So, I did this with vanilla JS.

As was mentioned before, there are two checkboxes with the same id. The id attribute needs to be unique for any element that uses one. So I changed `chkT` to a class.

I also changed the CSS property from `display: none;` to `visibility: hidden` so that the table doesn't jump around so much when it is shown/hidden. I added a class called `.show` and the property `visibility: visible!important` and then just add/remove that class as the different conditions are met.

I also removed the `onchange` attribute from the checkboxes and added the event listeners in the javascript.

Hopefully, this helps and didn't confuse you further. JQuery is an oaky tool, however, I would really recommend that you try and learn more of the vanilla Javascript methods to build a good JS foundation.

```js
function toggleTick_Change(event) {
  const chkAll = document.querySelector(`#chkAll`);
  const chkT = document.querySelectorAll(`.chkT`);
  const condPart = document.querySelector(`#conditional-part`);

  if (event.target.id === `chkAll`) chkT.forEach(n => n.checked = event.target.checked);

  const ckTCheckedCount = document.querySelectorAll(`.chkT:checked`).length

  if (ckTCheckedCount === 0) {
    chkAll.checked = false;
    chkAll.indeterminate = false;
  } else if (chkT.length === ckTCheckedCount) {
    chkAll.checked = true;
    chkAll.indeterminate = false;
  } else {
    chkAll.checked = false;
    chkAll.indeterminate = true;
  }

  ckTCheckedCount > 1 ? condPart.classList.add(`show`) : condPart.classList.remove(`show`);
}

document.querySelectorAll(`input[type=checkbox]`)
  .forEach(node => node.addEventListener(`click`, event => toggleTick_Change(event)));
```

```css
#conditional-part {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.show {
  visibility: visible!important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="container">

    <div id="page-container">

      <div id="page-header">
        <h3>Manage Deliveries</h3>
      </div>
      <div id="page-content">
        <table align="center">
          <tr id="conditional-part">
            <td class="input-group " role="group" aria-label="..." style="width: 85px; margin-top: 2px;">
              <input type="number" class="form-control input-xs" id="cpyCN{$rows.id}" name="cpyCN{$rows.id}" value="1" style="font-family: Raleway, Tahoma, Arial; font-size: 8pt; padding: 2px 2px 2px 10px;" placeholder="Copies" min="1" max="999" />

              <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button id="btnPrintCNTicked{$rows.id}" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" style="width: 40px;"
                                    onclick="javascript:btnPrintCNTicked_Click({$rows.id},$('#cpyCN{$rows.id}').val())">CN</button>
                            </span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>

        <div class="table-responsive" style="margin-top: 10px;">
          <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" style="font-size: 8pt;">
            <thead>
              <tr class="panel-default" style="height: 30px;">
                <th style="width: 20px;">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="chkAll" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;" title="Select All" />
                </th>
                <th style="width: 40px;">
                  #
                </th>
                <th style="width: 140px;">
                  DELIVERY NO / <br>DATE / TYPE
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr class="panel-default" style="height: 30px;">
                <td style="width: 20px;">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="chkT" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;" />
                </td>
                <td style="width: 140px;">
                  abcd
                </td>
                <td/>
              </tr>
              <tr class="panel-default" style="height: 30px;">
                <td style="width: 20px;">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="chkT" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;" />
                </td>
                <td style="width: 140px;">
                  1234
                </td>
                <td/>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <!--/id -page content-->
      </div>
      <!--/id -page container-->
    </div>
    <!-- /container -->
  </div>
  <!-- /content -->
```